# CSS Transitions to cross fade multiple images not working correctly

Tags: html, css, css-transitions

I have four images which I would like to cross fade with CSS Only.  I have researched the code to achieve this, which is based on [CSS = Awesome](http://css3.bradshawenterprises.com/cfimg/)

I have added what I have done to a [JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/f57pLppg/1/)

CSS

```
.upperlogo {
position:relative;
height: 100px;
width:1200px;
margin: 0 auto;
background-color:transparent;
}

@-webkit-keyframes upperlogoFadeInOut {
    0% {
        opacity:1;
    }
17% {
    opacity:0;
}
34% {
    opacity:0;
}
51% {
    opacity:0;
}
68% {
    opacity:0;
}
85% {
    opacity:0;
}
100% {
    opacity:1;
}
}


@-moz-keyframes upperlogoFadeInOut {
0% {
    opacity:1;
}
17% {
    opacity:0;
}
25% {
    opacity:0;
}
92% {
    opacity:0;
}
100% {
    opacity:1;
}
}

@-o-keyframes upperlogoFadeInOut {
0% {
    opacity:1;
}
17% {
    opacity:0;
}
25% {
    opacity:0;
}
92% {
    opacity:0;
}
100% {
    opacity:1;
}
}

@keyframes upperlogoFadeInOut {
0% {
    opacity:1;
}
17% {
    opacity:0;
}
25% {
    opacity:0;
}
92% {
    opacity:0;
}
100% {
    opacity:1;
}
}



.upperlogo img {
position:absolute;
left:0;
}

.upperlogo img {
-webkit-animation-name: upperlogoFadeInOut;
-webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
-webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
-webkit-animation-duration: 16s;

-moz-animation-name: upperlogoFadeInOut;
-moz-animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
-moz-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
-moz-animation-duration: 16s;

-o-animation-name: upperlogoFadeInOut;
-o-animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
-o-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
-o-animation-duration: 16s;

animation-name: upperlogoFadeInOut;
animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
animation-iteration-count: infinite;
animation-duration: 16s;
}

.upperlogo img:nth-of-type(1) {
-webkit-animation-delay: 16s;
-moz-animation-delay: 16s;
-o-animation-delay: 16s;
animation-delay: 16s;
}

.upperlogo img:nth-of-type(2)) {
-webkit-animation-delay: 12s;
-moz-animation-delay: 12s;
-o-animation-delay: 12s;
animation-delay: 12s;
}

.upperlogo img:nth-of-type(3) {
-webkit-animation-delay: 8s;
-moz-animation-delay: 8s;
-o-animation-delay: 8s;
animation-delay: 8s;
}

.upperlogo img:nth-of-type(4) {
-webkit-animation-delay: 4s;
-moz-animation-delay: 4s;
-o-animation-delay: 4s;
animation-delay: 4s;
}
```

A couple of the images end up muddy between each other and I get a blank screen for a few seconds also.  I can't get my head around this.  What I wish to achieve is always having an image visable and them transitioning smoothly between each other.

Comment: You want 4 images to participate in smooth opacity transition infinitely or 3 images to do opacity transition on 1 background static image?

Comment: Hi Aman, oh, I am not sure of the answer to that.  I don't want the transparent white background to appear as it currently does.  I wish to always see one of the four images with them cycling evenly.  If one is static I don't suppose it makes a difference and may help where browsers don't like the code and will display it.

Comment: Let me know if the dupe link doesn't solve your issue

Comment: It did thanks.  Didn't spot that one.

Answer (score 1):

A simple solution here would be to use the javascript setInterval method to repeat your keyframe animation.

However, to do this with pure CSS, you can change the background of your element and use the keyframes to determine the length of each fadein/out between images. Removed vendor prefixes for clarity:

```css
   .img-loader {
      display: none; 
      background: url("https://globaleyes.blob.core.windows.net/website/ENGLISH-flag-graphic.png"), url("https://globaleyes.blob.core.windows.net/website/SPAIN-flag-graphic.png"), url("https://globaleyes.blob.core.windows.net/website/PORTUGUESE-flag-graphic.png"), url("https://globaleyes.blob.core.windows.net/website/BRAZIL-flag-graphic.png");
}

    .upperlogo {
        width: 100%;
        height: 50px;
        margin-top: 40px;
        background: url('https://globaleyes.blob.core.windows.net/website/ENGLISH-flag-graphic.png') center center no-repeat;
    background-size: contain;
    }

    @keyframes upperlogoFadeInOut1 {
        0% {
            background: url('https://globaleyes.blob.core.windows.net/website/ENGLISH-flag-graphic.png') center center no-repeat;
            background-size: contain;
        }
        20% {
            background: url('https://globaleyes.blob.core.windows.net/website/ENGLISH-flag-graphic.png') center center no-repeat;
            background-size: contain;
        }
        25% {
            background: url('https://globaleyes.blob.core.windows.net/website/SPAIN-flag-graphic.png') center center no-repeat;
            background-size: contain;
        }
        45% {
            background: url('https://globaleyes.blob.core.windows.net/website/SPAIN-flag-graphic.png') center center no-repeat;
            background-size: contain;
        }
        50% {
            background: url('https://globaleyes.blob.core.windows.net/website/PORTUGUESE-flag-graphic.png') center center no-repeat;
            background-size: contain;
        }
        70% {
            background: url('https://globaleyes.blob.core.windows.net/website/PORTUGUESE-flag-graphic.png') center center no-repeat;
            background-size: contain;
        }
        75% {
            background: url('https://globaleyes.blob.core.windows.net/website/BRAZIL-flag-graphic.png') center center no-repeat;
            background-size: contain;
        }
        95% {
            background: url('https://globaleyes.blob.core.windows.net/website/ENGLISH-flag-graphic.png') center center no-repeat;
            background-size: contain;
        }
        100% {
            background: url('https://globaleyes.blob.core.windows.net/website/ENGLISH-flag-graphic.png') center center no-repeat;
            background-size: contain;
        }
    }


    .upperlogo {
       animation: upperlogoFadeInOut1 20s ease-in-out infinite;
    }
```

```html
<div class="img-loader"></div>
<div class="upperlogo"></div>
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks Mark, it was a duplicate albeit I didn't notice.  I now have it working with the other solution but have +1'ed your effort thanks.